# What is the best way to declare transient dependencies between compile and runtime with Eclipse?

Tags: java, maven, ant, build-process, gradle

We are looking to revamp our Java build process on Eclipse.  Currently we use Gradle!  As a part of that effort we are looking at whether we are using Gradle in the best possible way.  We use the Eclipse plugin for Gradle and declare our dependencies with compile.  Unfortunately this adds a ton of transient dependencies with our generated Eclipse projects which is not desirable.  These extra dependencies are only valid at runtime.

So, is there a way to declare a dependency ONCE in Gradle and have its compile dependency set to the first level of dependency and its runtime dependency set to the first level plus transient dependencies?

Currently we use the @jar syntax with compile which gives us the first level dependency for compile, but we still have to declare that dependency again for runtime.  Not ideal because we have two places to go in order to update a dependency.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I would suggest you create a very simple example showing exactly what  you want to achieve, and present that in the question.  If I understand you correctly this is what `<optional>true</optional>` does for a dependency in Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean *transitive* dependencies.

If you only want direct dependencies to appear on Gradle's compile class path, your current solution seems reasonable. (In the future we want to have a more accurate compile class path out-of-the-box.) Potential improvements are to make the `compile` configuration non-transitive (rather than using `@jar`) or to write a plugin that provides a custom dependency syntax, thereby making the duplication between compile and runtime dependencies go away.

However, this won't help you with Eclipse, as Eclipse has no notion of separate compile and runtime class paths. The only way out is to make run configurations responsible for providing the runtime class path, but this might be difficult to set up (e.g. run configurations are often created on-the-fly), and Gradle doesn't have any out-of-the-box support for this. You could use the generic XML hooks of Gradle's Eclipse plugin to generate run configurations, but I'm not sure if the Eclipse Gradle integration would pick them up.

Due to these difficulties, most Eclipse developers put all runtime dependencies on the Eclipse project class path (regardless of whether they are using Gradle or not), despite the obvious disadvantages.

Our vision is that Gradle can one day act as the build engine for Eclipse. Once this happens, discrepancies between IDE and build tool (class paths, code generation, integration testing, etc.) will be a thing of the past. Gradle can already act as the build engine for NetBeans today, and soon also for IntelliJ IDEA (driven by the requirements for Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

While I certainly agree with @Peter that an overhaul of the Eclipse build process is a long-term goal, in the short term you may be able to accomplish what you want using Maven and m2eclipse. Whether the tradeoffs of moving to Maven are worth that extra control are entirely up to you.

Comment: I don't see how this would solve the problem at hand, as Maven puts way too much on the compile class path as well. At best, you'd have to reconfigure the Maven build in the same way Richard already did for his Gradle build, and I think it would lead to similar problems when executing code from Eclipse.

Comment: It's not a great solution, but m2eclipse does manage the compile and runtime classpaths correctly.

Comment: Define "correctly". Maven puts way too much on its own compile class path, and m2eclipse won't differ. And probably m2eclipse uses at least the Maven compile class path (if not runtime) for the Eclipse class path, which, I assume, will still be used in some ways (e.g. for editing/search/navigation).

Comment: I mean that a build run using m2eclipse will use the same classpaths as the build run using Maven standalone (as opposed to what I understood to be a problem with a mismatch between the Gradle and Eclipse classpaths).

Comment: That's certainly good, but it won't solve Richard's problem that way too much stuff is on the (Maven compile and) Eclipse class path. He'll still get tons of transitive dependencies.

Comment: In Maven, it's quite simple to exclude downstream transitive dependencies using the `scope` clause, and I've frequently had to do that when some library includes a dependency on `log4j` when I'm using `slf4j`.

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple and robust way to exclude *all* transitive dependencies in Maven (which is what's desired here). Also, my guess is that you'd nevertheless see all runtime dependencies while coding in the Eclipse editor. (Feel free to prove me wrong on this one.)